# How do these table sizes make sense?

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a MyISAM table, that contains just one field, a SMALL INT. That field has an index on it, and there are 5.6 million records.

So in theory 5.6mil * 2 bytes (smallint) = 11MB (approx), but the data file of the table is 40MB, why so different?

The index file takes up 46MB, would would it be bigger than the data file?

Here is the create table:

```
CREATE TABLE `key_test` (
  `key2` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `key2` (`key2`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: Possibly one for the DBAs, but nice question all the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some overhead.

First, some controllable 'variables':

`myisam_data_pointer_size` defaults to 6 (bytes).
`myisam_index_pointer_size` defaults to 1 less than that.

For the data (`.MYD`):

- N bytes for up to 8*N `NULLable` columns.  (N=0 for your table.)
- 1 byte for "deleted".  You do have this.
- `DELETEd` rows leave gaps.
- When a record is deleted, the gap is filled in with a data_pointer to the next record.  This implies that the smallest a row can be is 6 bytes.

So:  1 + MAX(row_length, 6) = 7 bytes per row.

If you had 3 `SMALLINTs`, the table would be the same size.

For the index (`.MYI`):

- BTree organization has some overhead; if randomly built, it settles in on about 69% full.
- A 6-byte pointer (byte offset into .MYD, DYNAMIC) is needed in each leaf row.
- Links within the BTree are a 5-byte row that is controlled by an unlisted setting (`myisam_index_pointer_size`).

So: row_length + 6 per record, plus some overhead.  46M sounds like the data was sorted so that the index was built "in order".

Beyond that, my memory of MyISAM details is fading.